# Resgistering javascript in a usercontrol

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, registerclientscriptblock, registerstartupscript

I am trying to use google maps and for that I have made a usercontrol where I am trying to register a javascript, but again like always it did not get registered, so I tried to register it code behind using clientscript. But again, the same problem. It does not gets registered.

The following code is written in the page load event of the usercontrol.

```
 ClientScriptManager script = Page.ClientScript;

        if (!script.IsStartupScriptRegistered(this.GetType(), "scriptKey"))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("function initialize() {");
            sb.AppendLine("var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(%%LAT%%, %%LONG%%);");
            sb.AppendLine("var myOptions = {");
            sb.AppendLine("zoom: 8,");
            sb.AppendLine("center: latlng,");
            sb.AppendLine("mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP");
            sb.AppendLine("};");
            sb.AppendLine("var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"\"%%CLIENTID%%\"\"), myOptions);");
            sb.AppendLine("}");


            sb = sb.Replace("%%CLIENTID%%", this.ClientID);


            sb = sb.Replace("%%LAT%%", (a1 == null ? 42.006160736084 : a1.latitude).ToString());
            sb = sb.Replace("%%LONG%%", (a1 == null ? -93.6386795043945 : a1.longitude).ToString());

            script.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptKey", sb.ToString(), false);
```

and then I try to use this control in an aspx page. Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the  tags.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function initialize() {");
        ......
        ......
        ......
        ......
        sb = sb.Replace("%%LAT%%", (a1 == null ? 42.006160736084 : a1.latitude).ToString());
        sb = sb.Replace("%%LONG%%", (a1 == null ? -93.6386795043945 : a1.longitude).ToString());

        sb.Append("</script>");
```

Comment: Alternatively if he doesn't want to add tags he could change the last parameter of script.RegisterStartupScript to true and it will add the script tags for him.

Comment: I did add the tag as well as tried with setting the last parameter to true.. does not work.